# GUI quota calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

We are new to python but working on creating a custom quote calculator, although we aren't getting an output after clicking calculate. The code is below. Any advice is helpful.

```
'''

Barrington Advisory Solutions
BIS Development Team Project

'''

import tkinter

service = { #This is the dictionary that holds all of the services and their associated prices
'Mergers and Acquisitions':3000,
'Business Valuations':2000,
'Financial Analysis & Operational Ideas':5000,
'Strategic Planning Services':3500,
'Specialized Strategic Consultion Services':4000,
'Litigation Support':6000,
'': 0
}

services = [ #This is the list that holds all of the services (Used for the GUI output)
'',
'Mergers and Acquisitions',
'Business Valuations',
'Financial Analysis & Operational Ideas',
'Strategic Planning Services',
'Specialized Strategic Consultion Services',
'Litigation Support'
]

window = tkinter.Tk() #Creates the window (GUI)

class QuotaCalc:

## A class that asks for data about a client and then calculates
## both the time required for the service and the total estimate cost

    def __init__(self, main, cust_name = 'none', co_size = 0, option1=None, option2=None, option3=None):      ##This initializes the class with all of the variables that we will use

        self.co_name = tkinter.Label(main, text = 'Customer/Company Name', font=('Arial Narrow', 20)).grid(row=20, column=1)       #This displays text, the font is the font, and this tells the program what to display
        self.co_name_input = tkinter.Entry(main).grid(row=20, column=3)      #Allows user to input information       #by putting both on row 0, it aligns the text
    #can add in blank labels to space out the boxes (reduce the font to something small)

        clicked = tkinter.StringVar()           #initializing "clicked" as a string variable
        clicked2 = tkinter.StringVar()
        clicked3 = tkinter.StringVar()

        clicked.set(services[0])                #Text to be displayed on the menu dropdown
        clicked2.set(services[0])
        clicked3.set(services[0])

        timeRequired = 0

        self.co_size = tkinter.Label(main, text = 'Company Size', font=('Arial Narrow', 20)).grid(row=40, column=1)
        self.comp_size_input = tkinter.Entry(main).grid(row=40, column=3)

        self.option_1 = tkinter.Label(main, text = 'Service 1 Needed', font=('Arial Narrow', 20)).grid(row=60, column=1)    
        self.drop = tkinter.OptionMenu( main , clicked , *service ).grid(row = 60, column = 3)                              #refers to the set number of services for dropdown

        self.option_2 = tkinter.Label(main, text = 'Service 2 Needed', font=('Arial Narrow', 20)).grid(row=80, column=1)
        self.drop2 = tkinter.OptionMenu( main , clicked2 , *service ).grid(row = 80, column = 3)

        self.option_3 = tkinter.Label(main, text = 'Service 3 Needed', font=('Arial Narrow', 20)).grid(row=100, column=1)
        self.drop3 = tkinter.OptionMenu( main , clicked3 , *service ).grid(row = 100, column = 3)

        activated = True

        self.bt = tkinter.Button(main, text='Calculate', command = self.myClick, fg = "purple", bg = "light blue").grid(row=120, column=2)     ##fg is foreground (color), bg is background (color)
        #Need to convert to when the button presses, it runs other functions of the class

        time_req = tkinter.Label(window, text = 'Time Required', font=('Arial Narrow', 20)).grid(row=140, column=1)

        total_cost = tkinter.Label(window, text = 'Price Quote', font=('Arial Narrow', 20)).grid(row=160, column=1)
    #make a boolean to see if the button has been clicked and set it to false, when the boolean becomes true run the functions that do the math

    def getTime(self, comp_size_input):
        
        if self.comp_size_input == 0:                        #This determines how much time will be necessary based on the size of the company
            self.timeRequired = 0
        elif self.comp_size_input <= 20:
            self.timeRequired = 1
        elif self.comp_size_input <= 40:
            self.timeRequired = 2
        elif self.comp_size_input <= 60:
            self.timeRequired = 3
        elif self.comp_size_input <= 80:
            self.timeRequired = 4
        elif self.comp_size_input <= 100:
            self.timeRequired = 5
        elif self.comp_size_input <= 150:
            self.timeRequired = 6
        else:
            self.timeRequired = 8

        #return timeRequired

    def calcCost(self):                                 #This calculates the total cost of the services
        cost = self.timeRequired * service[self.drop]
        if self.option2 != '':
            cost += self.timeRequired * service[self.drop2]
        if self.option3 != '':
            cost += self.timeRequired * service[self.drop3]

        #return cost

    def myClick(self):

        timeRequired = self.getTime()
        cost = self.calcCost
        
        myLabel = tkinter.Label(window,text = cost)
        myLabel.grid(row=140, column=3)
        myLabel2 = tkinter.Label(window, text = timeRequired)
        myLabel2.grid(row=160, column=3)
    '''
    if name == "main":

    #calc = QuotaCalc(name, size, option1, option2, option3)
    #timeRequired = calc.getTime()
    #time_required = tkinter.Label(window, text = timeRequired, font=('Arial Narrow', 20)).grid(row=175, column=85)       #print("Time rquired: ", str(timeRequired) + " month(s)")

    #totalCost = calc.calcCost()
    #totalCost = format(totalCost, '.2f')
    #total_costs = tkinter.Label(window, text = 'Price Quote', font=('Arial Narrow', 20)).grid(row=200, column=85)    #print("Price quote: $", totalCost)
    '''

logo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\micia\OneDrive\Desktop\Barrington.png")
##YOU MUST USE THE FILE PATH TO THE LOGO ON YOUR OWN COMPUTER
##THIS SHOWS MY PERSONAL FILE PATH

w1 = tkinter.Label(window, image=logo).grid(row=0, column = 2)

window.title('Barrington Advisory Quota Calculator') #Window Title
window.geometry('1000x500') #Sets the size of the window
#window.configure(bg='light blue') <- If we want to change the color of the background

e = QuotaCalc(window)

window.mainloop() #Tells the program to continue running until the GUI is closed
```

Answer (score 0):

`cost = self.calcCost` -- that line does not call the function.  It sets `cost` to POINT to the function.  You need parens: `cost = self.calcCost()`.

Is this a class assignment?  If so, fine, but if you're doing this professionall, throw `tkinter` into the trash can.  It has always been a hack.  Use a real UI library, like wxWidgets or Qt.